# Configure bash globbing

Tags: bash, wildcards

After coming from cygwin, I'm quite confused about the bash (version 4.1.5) globbing on my Ubuntu 10.4. I'd love one of the following two possibilities:

- ignore `.` and `..`, match everything else
- ignore filenames starting with a dot unless given explicitly

The current behavior is plain strange:

```
cd; ls .*
```

says "ls: cannot access .*: No such file or directory" although I explicitly asked for filenames starting with a dot.

```
cd; ls .gnupg/*.gpg
```

complains as well although I'm asking for files not starting with a dot (it's just the directory name what starts with a dot).

#### Output of `shopt -p`

(removed)

#### The solution

I've changed `shopt` to values from another user (not having this problem) and it didn't help. Then I came to the idea to bisect my `.bashrc` and find the offending line which contained something like `GLOBIGNORE='.[!/.]*:..[!/]*:*/.[!/.]*:*/..[!/]*:`...

I've replaced it by `GLOBIGNORE='.:..'`, which does nearly what I want, and it works.

Comment: I've never seen this behavior.  Could you edit your question to include the output of `shopt -p`, please?

Comment: This behavior is very strange, indeed. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I must answer my own question. It was `GLOBIGNORE`. From the man page:

*A  colon-separated  list of patterns defining the set of filenames to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a pathname expansion pattern also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.*

Answer (score 1):

The "ls: cannot access .*: No such file or directory" error sounds like there are permissions problems with the current directory.  I can reproduce it with:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/tmp/tmp
$ cd ~/tmp/tmp
$ ls .*
.:

..:
tmp
$ chmod u-r .
$ ls .*
ls: cannot access .*: No such file or directory
$ ls -ldn .
d-wxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 2012-03-12 18:31 .
$ chmod u+r .
$ ls .*
.:

..:
tmp
```

I'd suggest running `chmod +r .` and trying the `ls .*` again.

Comment: That's interesting, but can't be the cause. The concerned directory is my `$HOME` and the permissions are right (700).

Answer (score 0):

It is more than likely that you have no files being matched by the globs. If no files are matched, `bash` by default interprets `*` literally. You may wish to set `nullglob` using `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid this (although this will leave the command barren of arguments altogether if no files are matched).

Comment: You're right in what you're saying about not matching. But it should match, there're tons of `.foo` files in my home directory, etc.

Comment: At the very least, `.*` should match `.` and `..`, which means it should always match.

Comment: @MatthewScharley - Ah, good point.